# Text selection with javascript is not visible in chromium

Tags: javascript, html, input, selection

**Problem**: 
When text selection is set programmatically using `setSelectionRange` (in an input field narrower than the content) , the desired part is selected but the selection isn't scrolled into visibility. Seems to be occurring on chrome and opera. Works for Firefox and edge.

**State:** It's actually a known issue since 2014 according to the [chromium bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=331233). So i am mainly interested in a workaround because this issue causes some other weird side effect in my application.

I already tried timeouts, additional focus-blur pairs.

minimal case with the following input:

```
<input id="text" type="text" value="123456789" size="2"/>
```

and the following function:

```
function selectText() {
  var input=  document.getElementById("text");
  input.focus();
    setTimeout(function(){ //workaround for edge
      input.setSelectionRange(7,9,"forward");
    }, 1);
 }
```

Here's the [code](http://jsfiddle.net/mLsvL87a/) to try out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining a few different techniques, such as using `.focus()` and setting `.scrollLeft` to `scrollWidth`, you can relatively easily deal with this problem. Code sample below (based on the Fiddle provided), as well as in [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mLsvL87a/2/). Let me know if this works as expected in all browsers (only tested for Chrome).

```js
function selectText() {
  var input = document.getElementById("text");
  input.focus();

  var txt = input.value;
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("text").focus();
    document.getElementById("text").scrollLeft = document.getElementById("text").scrollWidth;
    document.getElementById("text").setSelectionRange(7, 9, "forward");
    document.getElementById("selection").innerHTML = "selection is: " + txt.substring(input.selectionStart, input.selectionEnd);
  }, 1);


}
```

```html
<p id="selection"></p>
<input id="text" type="text" value="123456789" size="2" />
<input type="button" value="Select" id="select" onclick="selectText()">
```

Comment: This only works if the selection is at the end of the content but fails for 

 `<input id="text" type="text" value="12345678987654321" size="2" />`

scrolling is a good idea though, maybe i can scroll exactly where the selection starts.

Comment: @vasf scrolling was the first thing that came to mind when I saw your question. You can easily alter my code to scroll to a specific offset, so that the selection is visible regardless of its actual position.

Comment: yeah,    `document.getElementById("text").scrollLeft = document.getElementById("text").scrollWidth*(input.selectionStart/input.value.length);`  seems to do the trick! 
http://jsfiddle.net/o329oao2/